# How to make sure Web3 / Metamask recognize that I am the smart contract owner?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to read some data from a smart contract that I have created and available on the main net here:
https://snowtrace.io/address/0x98608c1e3ae104e7a11ea2879b44669a1c38b73d#code

When I try to interact with my smart contract via Web3 library I am able to read all public details, except for one called: getCurrentBalance()

which requires owner permission (which I am). I triple checked to make sure that I am on the right owner account in Metamask.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Web 3 Demo</title>
<script src='node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="getCurrentBalance();">Get Current Contract Balance</button>
    Status: <span id="status">Loading...</span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the index.js:

```
// Check metamask installation and connect to site
async function loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        window.ethereum.enable();
    }
}

// In the html file there is a span called status this function updates the print out
function updateStatus(status) {
    const statusEl = document.getElementById('status');
    statusEl.innerHTML = status;
    console.log(status);
}

// This function links to the smart contract for interactions
async function loadContract() {
    return await new window.web3.eth.Contract([{"inputs": [],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_liquitdateTo","type":"address"}],"name":"destroySmartContract","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundsReceived","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getCurrentBalance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getFunds","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"_bool","type":"bool"}],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"smartContractAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tresury","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}], '0x98608C1e3ae104E7A11EA2879b44669a1c38b73D');
}

// This is the main program function that calls all the previous ones
async function load() {
    await loadWeb3();
    window.contract = await loadContract();
    updateStatus('Ready!');
}

async function getCurrentBalance() {
    updateStatus('fetching...');
    const getCurrentBalance = await window.contract.methods.getCurrentBalance().call();
    updateStatus(`Current Contract Balance: ${getCurrentBalance}`);
}

load();
```

This is the error I get in the console:

[image]

How to read the getCurrentBalance() from the smart contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getCurrentBalance()` function of the smart is defined as:

```
function getCurrentBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    require(owner == msg.sender, 'You are not the owner!!!');
    require(paused == false, 'Contract Status: Paused!!!');
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

In your case, the first `require()` condition fails with the "You are not the owner!!!" error message, because the address invoking the function is not the expected value stored in the `owner` variable.

A systematic solution would be to invoke the `getCurrentBalance()` function from the `owner` address:

```
// where `0x123` is the `owner` address
await window.contract.methods.getCurrentBalance().call({from: '0x123'});
```

However, since the function effectively just returns the contract address balance, you can also perform a workaround, and query the contract address balance directly from the blockchain (without invoking the contract function):

```
await web3.eth.getBalance('0x98608C1e3ae104E7A11EA2879b44669a1c38b73D');
```